# capistrano put() and upload() both failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

With capistrano, I am deploying a Rails application from Mac OS X 10.5 to CentOS 5.2

Note that deploy.rb and the server environment have not changed in over a year.

There is a task within our deploy.rb file called `upload`:

```
put(File.read( file ),"#{shared_path}/#{filename}", :via => :scp)
```

This fails each and every time with the following exception:

```
No such file or directory - /srv/ourapp/releases/20100104194410/config/database.yml
```

My local copy of config/database.yml is failing to upload properly. I've verified it's not our internet connection, as this happens on three different connections and two different systems.

I've also tried to swap out put() for upload() but get the same result; also, dropping :via => :scp, and/or trying to force :sftp instead similarly fails.

Relevant info:

$ cap -V
Capistrano v2.5.10

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i686-darwin9.6.0]

Comment: Could you give a little more context on the 'upload' task? Does it upload only the database.yml file or is it uploading other files also? Do the other files upload correctly? Also, would you be able to include more information from Capistrano's error message? As much of the output as you can give would be helpful.

Comment: It's just the database.yml file. That's the full error message...

The file uploads successfully to the src path:
`$ cat /srv/app/shared/database.yml | wc -l -> 99`

I can also verify that the dest path exists.

Comment: Where is that error coming from? Is it something you're getting from the Rails app itself, or something you're getting during the Capistrano deploy? I'd assumed it was during the deploy, but that doesn't make sense, now that I think about it more, since the `put` command is putting into the shared directory, and the file not found error is in the release directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like Capistrano is successfully uploading the files, but Rails is failing to start because it can't find the `deploy.yml` file. This might be happening during the Capistrano deploy as part of the `deploy:restart` task, making it look like a Capistrano error.

Based on the information you've given Capistrano is uploading the file to `/svr/ourapp/shared/` and Rails is almost definitely looking for it in `/svr/ourapp/releases/20100104194410/config/`.

If that's the case, what you'll need to do is create a task which symlinks the shared database file to the expected location then add a hook so that task will be run after finalize_update. For instance:

```
task :symlink_database do
  run "ln -s #{shared_path}/database.yml #{latest_release}/config/database.yml"
end

after 'deploy:finalize_update', :symlink_database
```

Comment: thanks Emily, I ended up doing exactly that. However, a new issue has arisen - capistrano is now removing the latest release directory sometime after it kicks off a server restart. Very frustrating.

Comment: Most likely reason for that would probably be `deploy:rollback` getting triggered for some reason. That's definitely part of the default rollback task. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :upload_settings, :roles => :app do
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config/"
    top.upload "config/database.yml", "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml", :via => :scp
  end

  task :symlink_yml, :roles => :app do
    run "ln -sf #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
end

after 'deploy:setup', 'deploy:upload_settings'
after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_yml'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is purely from a server-side view, but have you checked to make sure that the user you're using to upload has proper permissions for the directory?

Doing a recursive change for the user (or group) depending on your server environment should fix this.

```
chown -R user_name_here /srv/ourapp/releases/
chgrp -R group_name_here /srv/ourapp/releases/
```

You might also want to clean up any code repositories e.g. `git gc` or `svn cleanup`. As well as updating any symbolic links.

Answer (score 0):

The "No such file or directory" error occurs when you are trying to copy a file to a destination path that does not exist. As far as I know, the put and upload methods of Capistrano merely attempt to transfer the file, but do not make the required path. Is it possible that the config/ directory, or even the shared_path itself, has not been created when you are trying to upload this file?

Comment: Hi, the paths both exist at the time of the upload. This deploy.rb has been in use, virtually unchanged, for more than a year.